# Basic Python Reclass question in Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator

I'm trying to reclass values in field calculator using Python.

I want any value >= '5' to remain the same (return same value). Anything else to be = '0'.

**Yes, DIST_EDGE are numbers.**

I'm getting an invalid syntax error in Line 1 (see below)

Here's what I came up with (new script following comments):

[image]

Error Message:

[image]

Comment: Is the data type for DIST_EDGE string or numeric? String values are accessed with quotes, numbers are not.

Comment: Once you call the function Reclass(!POINTS_Adelard.DIST_EDGE!), the passed value is stored in a variable, no '!'. I've updated my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the data type for DIST_EDGE is numeric, the function should be (note, no quotes):

```
def Reclass(dist):
    if dist >= 5:
        return dist
    else:
        return 0
```

However, if DIST_EDGE is a string data type, you must cast it to a number before making your comparison:

```
def Reclass(dist):
    if int(dist) >= 5:
        return dist
    else:
        return '0'
```

Comment: These functions will work. The actual problem with the OP's code is that his function is using `!POINTS_Adelard.DIST_EDGE!` as a *parameter name*, which is of course invalid Python syntax. Replacing those references in the function (but not the final function *call*) with `dist` (as in @phloem's examples) will resolve this.